# How to put color to an image in jQuery

Tags: javascript

May I ask a question.

I'm trying to put color to the images which is PNG format in jQuery.

What I've done is as below.

I create a color pallet to choose desire color from by clicking on relevant color box. Then, I click on the image which I want it get paint. But , the result is NOT as I expected. The color is filled into background of the image ,but not to the image.

My code is as below;

**HTML**

```
<img class="deer" src="images/deer.PNG" alt="">
```

**JavaScript**

```
let color = "";

$(".container").click(function(){
  color = $(this).css("background-color");
})

$("img").click(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", color);
})
```

My result is as below;

[image]

Then, I change the property "background-color" to "color". But nothing happen to the image.

So, Please help me to put the color into the images.

Comment: You can't manipulate pixel-based images with CSS (other than what's possible with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)). It might be possible with SVG format.

Comment: The images I displayed are individual images which are inserted in seperate <img> tag

Comment: you cant change color in  image that are in png format

Comment: what do you mean with "color an image"?  The background-color? You already changed this. The color of the object itself? The line-color of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I will sugest to make a container, with your image inside, and an element who will be your background

```css
.container{
  width:250px;
  height:400px;
  position:relative;
}

.img-background,img{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-background"></div>
  <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/pineapple/pineapple_PNG2756.png" alt="" />
</div>
```